# Writing in-line equations on multiple lines using \displaystyle

Tags: equations, formatting, displaystyle

I'm trying to write equations on multiple lines using `\displaystyle`. I can use `\\` for line breaks but can't align or put horizontal space on the second line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\displaystyle
(n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1 = n^2+2n+1+5n+5+1 \\
%\hspace{4em}
%%&
%\quad
= n^2+7n+7
$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Note that the equation is in-line and should start at the bullet point. I have made several attempts to indent the second line but the output always looks like

[image]

(Note that this is a MWE - the actual equation I'm typesetting is more complicated.) Is there a way to align the two lines of the equation at the `=` sign? This is indicated by the red arrow in the picture.

Comment: Well, that's the cause for the `align` environment ;-) `\begin{align} (n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1 &= n^2+2n+1+5n+5+1 \\ &= n^2+7n+7 \end{align}` and its variants `alignat` and `aligned` etc.

Comment: yes but I want the equation to start on the line with the bullet point, not after it

Comment: That's why I suggested `aligned` as well ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `aligned` with top vertical alignment.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item $\begin{aligned}[t]
       (n+1)^2+5(n+1)+1 &= n^2+2n+1+5n+5+1 \\
                        &= n^2+7n+7
      \end{aligned}$
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

I removed the packages that are unnecessary for the example; `amsfonts` is loaded by `amssymb` anyway.

Are you sure you want to continue using `latin1` for your documents?

[image]

Comment: No the `latin1` isn't necessary. It's just part of one of the "quick start" templates offered by my Latex editor.